# How to modularize an express app - with a function, a class and req.pipe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here below there are two `servers` and two `gqlServers`. All combinations of them work.

The challenge is to extend express with some additional predefined code patterns shared across several apps, exposed through additional methods.

**Which combination of a `server` and `gqlServer` is considered best practice and best for performance?**

`server`:

- server_A is a function that returns a class
- server_B is a function that returns a function

`gqlServer`:

- gqlServer_01 uses `req.pipe`
- gqlServer_02 has the original `express()` passed into it

```js
function gqlServer_01(options) {
    let gqlApp = express();
    gqlApp.use(options.route, function(req, res, next) {
        res.send('gqlServer 01');
        // next();
    });

    gqlApp.listen(8001, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`>> GQL Server running on 8001`);
    });
}
```

```js
function gqlServer_02(app, options) {
    app.use(options.route, function(req, res, next) {
        res.send('gqlServer 02');
        // next();
    });
}
```

```js
// THIS SERVER ?
function server_A(config = {}) {
    config = deepmerge(def_opt, config);
    let app = express();

    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.send('root');
        // next();
    });

    class Server {
        constructor(opt) {
            this.opt = opt;
        }

        gql(props = {}) {
            // THIS GQL SERVER ?
            gqlServer_01({ route: '/gql-01' });
            app.use('/gql-01', function(req, res) {
                req.pipe(request(`http://localhost:8001/gql-01`)).pipe(res);
            });

            // OR THIS GQL SERVER ?
            gqlServer_02(app, { route: '/gql-02' });
        }
    }

    app.listen(8000, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`>> Server running on 8000`);
    });

    return new Server(app, config);
}
```

```js
// OR THIS SERVER ?
function server_B(config = {}) {
    config = deepmerge(def_opt, config);
    let app = express();

    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.send('root');
        // next();
    });

    app.gql = function(props = {}) {
        // THIS GQL SERVER ?
        gqlServer_01({ route: '/gql-01' });
        app.use('/gql-01', function(req, res) {
            req.pipe(request(`http://localhost:8001/gql-01`)).pipe(res);
        });

        // OR THIS GQL SERVER ?
        gqlServer_02(app, { route: '/gql-02' });
    };

    app.listen(8000, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`>> Server running on 8000`);
    });

    return app;
}
```

The goal is to have the best solution in order to create an npm package out of this and reuse the methods over several projects easily. The project was highly simplified for the sake of clarity.

Comment: asking for best practices can sometimes attract downvotes if it's an opinion based topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will have performance issues in any of these examples, so the question remains which of them is more modular.

If you are willing to make an npm package out of these, you shouldn't be calling `express()` inside your server code. Instead you should be passing the `app` as a parameter. This will allow you to reuse existing express apps initialized elsewhere. For this reason I would go for `gqlServer_02`

You also want to create a new server each time you call the module function, so I'd go with `server_A` for this reason. However it needs to receive the express `app` as parameter, in order to reuse existing express objects. I would also put the `app.listen` call inside a function in the `Server` class.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I know it's opinionated but that's the kind of reasoning I was looking for.